# Unique Time (HH:MM) from Date within a multidimensional array

Tags: swift

I am pulling remote JSON data that I decode into new Struct objects, defined:

```
struct CompEntry: Codable {
    let objectId: String
    let playerId: String
    let compId: String
    let teeTime: TeeTime
    let roundNo: Int
}

struct TeeTime: Codable {
    let time: Date
}
```

This is a record of every player playing in a competition. There will (must) only be 3 players per tee time.

For the UI, I need to extract the unique tee times contained within each player's entry. UI experience will be to select the tee time, then select the player (from a max of 3 players within each tee time).

I read about unique values in Swift arrays, and the Set syntax, specifically following this blog:
https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/unique-values-removing-duplicates-array/

I have tried it with:

```
let times = uniqueTimes(from: compEntries) // RETURNS ARRAY OF DATES [Date]
print("Times: \(times)")
compTeeTimes = times // THE OFFENDING LINE
```

But I get the following error message:

> Cannot assign value of type '[Date]' to type 'Set<Date>'

If I comment the offending line, the print output is:

> Times: [2020-08-29 07:00:00 +0000, 2020-08-29 07:00:00 +0000,
> 2020-08-29 07:09:00 +0000, 2020-08-29 07:09:00 +0000, 2020-08-29
> 07:09:00 +0000, 2020-08-29 07:18:00 +0000]

I don't see the difference passing in a pre-existing `[Date]` variable to the `Set<Date>` initializer from the blog that writes out the entire array contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is very strict about types. You can assign a *literal* array to a Set, because Set conforms to ExpressibleByArrayLiteral; but you cannot assign an array *reference* to a Set. You can only assign a Set to a Set!

So you need to coerce your array explicitly to a Set:

```
compTeeTimes = Set(times)
```

Comment: thanks. From continued looking, I wonder if its because the Set<> definition is: `struct Set<Element> where Element : Hashable` and Date does not conform to Hashable? DateComponents is, but I would then need to coerce the array into DateComponents?

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. The question was the compilation error `Cannot assign value of type '[Date]' to type 'Set<Date>'` and I told you how to fix that. Other things that you are doing were not part of the question.

Comment: My apologies, @matt - I was reading more info before reading and interpreting your response. From your code, the Set object can be initialised with an existing array - which answers the question.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's backwards. Hashable implies Equatable. Equatable doesn't imply Hashable.

Comment: Yes but that isn’t what you said. And it isn’t relevant to the problem or the answer. We know it’s Hashable or there couldn’t be a Set of them. It’s Hashable because it’s Hashable, not because it’s Equatable.